# Amcharts v. 3 not showing all the data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, amcharts

I am passing data through my MVC Controller to render an Amcharts (v. 3) plotting grid. The data being passed through the Controller to the javascript is correct and is showing everything that I want:

[image: JS Data]

The JS that I am using is the following:

```
        var chart = AmCharts.getChart('coopChart');
        chart.dataProvider = filteredData;
        chart.validateData();
```

The filteredData is the data that is to be shown and as I said it is showing the 16 plots that I want rendered.

However, when the grid is rendered, it is only showing 3 plots for some reason instead of the 16 that I am wanting to show:

[image]

My only thought is for some reason chart.validateData() (which is a built in Amcharts function) is filtering out the data. Does anyone know what would cause it to not show all the data?

Comment: AmCharts doesn't modify your dataProvider. Looking at the last datapoint in your screenshot, it appears that your data isn't sorted in date ascending order, which might explain part of the issue. Post a fiddle with your config and sample of your data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @xorspark You nailed it with the dates not being ordered. Thank you so much. What I'm doing in the controller is combining multiple lists together and so the dates are getting jumbled up as a result. After I did an order by dates the chart is now showing all the plots. Once again, thank you for your keen awareness of that and for answering my question.